# How is the past tense in this sentence translated?

Tags: grammar

I'm studying Japanese adjectives right now, and I see that adjectives can be formed to refer to past tense.

For example, 自転車は楽だったです。

So, I'm trying to understand a little bit better how the ～だった works. Is it used like, "the bike used to be comfortable", or "the bike (I was riding) was comfortable (when I was riding it)."

Comment: Apparently, [だったです is used by some speakers](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1025516725). Did you copy the sentence from sonewhere (where?), or did you come up with it youself (did you mean だったんです or でした)?

Comment: I came up with the sentence myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「[自転車]{じてんしゃ}は[楽]{らく}だったです。」

**This is ungrammatical**.  As a Japanese-speaker, I do know that a few of us would actually say it, but if one said or wrote it in school, it would certainly be corrected.

The correct sentence would be:

> 「自転車は楽でした。」 or
>
> 「自転車は楽だった。」

The former is a little politer than the latter.

Now, onto how to translate it..

To tell the truth, it is rather difficult without context.  A very short sentence/phrase like this can mean a few different things without any context to go with it.

Without context, most native speakers would think of the following.

> "The bicycle ride was comfortable."
>
> "The bike felt comfortable."
>
> "(Going there by) bicycle was easier (than doing so by other methods of transportation)."

**It would not be taken to include the meaning of "used to" unless the context clearly suggested it.  It would be taken to refer to the simple "near" past.**

Comment: I'd like just to add that だった is the past tense of です, so だったです would be a double affirmative, which is incorrect; except, I think, when it's a quote of an affirmation, but the sentence content doesn't indicate this possibility (no quotation marks or と/って particles after the quote).