# Could a verb or adjective in the past tense 〜た refer to something no longer true?

Tags: meaning, auxiliaries

I found the following sentences on a website teaching people the order of using the 助動詞.

> - 彼は人に笑われる。
> - 彼を人に笑われさせる。
> - 彼を人に笑われさせたい。
> - 彼を人に笑われさせたくない。
> - 彼を人に笑われさせたくなかった。
> - 彼を人に笑われさせたくなかっただろう。

I am wondering about the meaning of the second last sentence 彼を人に笑われさせたくなかった.

Should it be:

> I never wanted him to be laughed at by people.

Which might imply I still think so.

Or should it be:

> I used not to want him to be laughed at by people.

Which might imply I no longer think so.

Comment: Related: [how-is-the-past-tense-in-this-sentence-translated](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23787)

Answer (score 4):

Without additional context, Japanese is ambiguous on the distinction between preterite and imperfect (which is what you're asking about, even if you don't know the terminology).

Comment: Interestingly, the same is possible in  English: `Life was beautiful but not anymore, today is just a shadow that, without light, is lost.` and `Everywhere I looked was beautiful and it's still that way.`

Comment: Thanks , knowing even Japanese got confused by just this sentence, then that's okay.